# add an image into datagridview based on a condition

Tags: sqlite, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

i want to show an image in datagridview based on a condition (if the endday of subscribtion is < today then show a red cross image else show a checkmark image) , i have an sqlite database and i created a datagridviewimagecolumn called expired to shopw this images , but i'm not getting anything , here is the code

```
``for (int row = 0; row <= membersdashboarddatagrid.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
        {

            DateTime endday = Convert.ToDateTime(membersdashboarddatagrid.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);
            if (endday < DateTime.Today)
            {
                ((DataGridViewImageCell)membersdashboarddatagrid.Rows[row].Cells[0]).Value = Properties.Resources.delete;
            }
            else
            {
                ((DataGridViewImageCell)membersdashboarddatagrid.Rows[row].Cells[0]).Value = Properties.Resources._checked;

            }
        }`
```

Hope you could help me guys !
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that in each iteration of the `for` loop, the code is checking the “SAME” Cells `EndDay` value. Specifically, the line of code…

```
DateTime endday = Convert.ToDateTime(membersdashboarddatagrid.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);
```

The portion of this that is using the same cell is…

```
membersdashboarddatagrid.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value
```

The code above uses the SAME `CurrentRow.Cell[3].Value` with each iteration. Therefore, all the `Expire` images will be the same depending on what the `CurrentRows` `EndDay` value is. I am confident you want something like…

```
membersdashboarddatagrid.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i tried your solution and i still got the same issue !

Comment: @Younes Rahni Rahni ... you should edit your question and show the changes you made. I tested this and can verify that it does indeed work if implemented properly. Have you put a break-point on the if statement and stepped through the code to see if both conditions are met as expected? If both conditions are met and you see no changes, are you sure the images display at all.